# how to hide padding a gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

when I change number of columns to 2, additional space will be created. why ?

there is an additional space :

[image]

this is OK :

[image]

my grid view :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.ex28_grid_to_list.MainActivity" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click me"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="50dp"
        android:background="#e2e2e2"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#774646" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rrrr" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This button is used for changing number of columns :

```
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int i = 0 ;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (i == 0){
                gridView.setNumColumns(2);
                i = 1 ;
            }else{
                gridView.setNumColumns(1);
                i = 0 ;
            }

        }
    });
```

**updated :**

I changed my grid view to :

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:listSelector="@null"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

But it did not change.

**solved :**

set `scaleType` to `fitXY`

Comment: This is because you have set your imageview height and width to wrap_content. So it will adjust with its original size so just apply fix height and width. And scaleType to fitXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have set your imageview `height` and `width` to `wrap_content`. So it will adjust with its original size so just apply fix height and width. And `scaleType` to `fitXY`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the listSelector to null and remove the padding

remove this

```
android:padding="2dp"
```

add this

```
<GridView
    android:listSelector="@null" />
```

make your item fill_parent (Match_parent)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#774646" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rrrr" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change from  `android:background="#774646"` to  `android:background="@android:color/tranaparent"`

Comment: @AntonSavin It looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your GridView height ...

from

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Try this .. 
hope it will satisfy your need.